# Dealing with Subversion (TortoiseSVN), From Where to start?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn, svn-client

I want to develop a website in (ASP+C#) which deals with version control. In that application my scenario is as follow:

A user signing in to application and editing a post, the website may display to all users the previous and new version of the post?

I have searched and find that I must use the (TortoiseSVN). I found the solutions online for manually doing this. But when I searched how to do it with C#? only I found to use (SharpSVN). I have downloaded the (SharpSVN) and now I have Confused:

1. From where I should start with (SharpSVN) ?
2. The Post's Contents (which is editable, or using for versioning) are saved in a SQL-Server database. How to use those contents with (TortoiseSVN)?

**Any directions and advise, links or experience?**

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you want your ASP.NET application to interact with a repository, SharpSVN is the preferred method.

CollabNet has a [walkthrough for using SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm)

Content stored in SQL Server is not accessible with a version control client. You need to query the database directly, or use a framework which abstracts it & meshes with how your application is built.

Whatever you do, do **not** duplicate anything between SQL Server & the Subversion repository. It'll just become a massive headache.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it up, but when I am adding the svnserve.exe to create the service, it is creating successfully, but when I want to start it, it dosn't start. A message appear (**Error 1053 - The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion**). I have created the service through this statement from command line `sc create svnnew binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r D:\BCS-Project\SourceControl" displayName= "Subversion new Server" depend= Tcpip start= auto` . hope to help me with this. I searched but failed. thanks...

Comment: Installing & configuring svnserve is a completely different topic from the one you originally asked about.

Comment: Yes it is diffirent, but can you provide some instructions on this issue too? thanks for the answer

Comment: Getting a Subversion server online ought to be asked as a separate question.